# Replace file when exists not working in Spring Integration Smb

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to write files to smb folder, it works fine for the first write but when the same file is written again it throws error

*Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to rename [/remote-target-dir/smbTest.test.writing] to [/remote-target-dir/smbTest.test].; nested exception is jcifs.smb.SmbException: Cannot create a file when that file already exists.*

Im' using the `FileTransferringMessageHandler` which has `FileExistsMode.REPLACE` as default file exists mode but still it fails to replace.

I debugged into the `SmbSession` class, when flow reaches to this code in `rename(String _pathFrom, String _pathTo)` method

```
  if (this.smbShare.isReplaceFile() && smbFileTo.exists()) {
            smbFileTo.delete();
  }
```

I see that the `smbShare`'s `isReplaceFile()` is false, which is why I assume it is unable to delete the previous file with the same name

Here is the full code:

Connection:

```
 @Bean
public SmbSessionFactory smbSessionFactory() {
    SmbSessionFactory smbSession = new SmbSessionFactory();
    smbSession.setHost("localhost");
    smbSession.setPort(445);
    smbSession.setDomain("DESKTOP-07O79IT");
    smbSession.setUsername("Dell");
    smbSession.setPassword("changeIt");
    smbSession.setShareAndDir("Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Shared");
    smbSession.setSmbMinVersion(DialectVersion.SMB210);
    smbSession.setSmbMaxVersion(DialectVersion.SMB311);
    return smbSession;
}
```

Outbound to send files to smb:

```
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "storeToSmb")
@Bean
public MessageHandler smbMessageHandler(SmbSessionFactory smbSessionFactory) {
    FileTransferringMessageHandler<SmbFile> handler =
            new FileTransferringMessageHandler<>(smbSessionFactory);
    handler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(
            new LiteralExpression("/remote-target-dir"));
    handler.setFileNameGenerator(m -> "smbTest.test");
    handler.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
    return handler;
}
```

Gateway:

```
@Override
public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    File file  = new File("smbFile.txt");
    try(FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)){
        writer.write("This is sample smb write");
        messageGateway.storeToSmb(file);
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
    }
}
```

Can you please help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SmbSessionFactory` must come with the `setReplaceFile(true)`. The `FileTransferringMessageHandler` does nothing about its dependency and can't mutate it although it has its own logic about that `FileExistsMode.REPLACE`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked but why do session object has file replace option any specific reason?  sftp/ftp sessions doesn't have any such option.

Comment: Yeah... I see your point. According Git history this `repace` option on the `SmbShare` was introduced the same year as `FileExistsMode.REPLACE`. Since there is really no any particular reasons to have it over there in the session logic, but rather more control it via a transfer handler, plus rely on a possible failure from SMB if we can't really replace, I'd suggest to raise a GH issue in Spring Integration Extensions project to deprecate that option and remove in the future.

Comment: GH issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-extensions/issues/246